# String elements and object key values

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, object, foreach

**Thanks for reading**.

Let's say that I have this set of inputs:

```
const S = "1C 5A 10F 1F 5E"; //Int are rows and Char are columns (ie. seat in a movie theater)
const N = 10; // Number between 1 to 100000
const Ob = { "A": 1, "B": 2, "C": 3,"D": 5, "E": 7, "F": 11, "G": 13,"H": 17, "J": 19, "K": 23};
```

I want to create an Array size `N` where:

- `Int` value minus 1 is the position in the Array.
- `Char` is used to get its value in `Ob` and added it to the Array in the position of its corresponding `Int`.
- If the value of an `Int` repeats (value in the same row), the value in the Array of that position should multiply the previous value with the new value of the character in `Ob`.

For example (given the values provided above):

- Value `1C` from `S` should allocate the value of `C` from the `Ob` in the position 0 of the Array so that

```
A[0] === 3;
```

- If we would do it for all inputs above, the result should be

```
A = [33, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 11]
```

I have managed to do it with the code below

```
//Resulting Array
A = Array(N).fill(0)

//Get string Int and Char into two arrays
let Columns = S.replace(/\d/g,'').split(' ');
let Rows = S.replace(/[A-K]/g,'').split(' ').map(Number);

//Replace values in A based on Rows and Columns values
Rows.forEach((value,i) => {A[value - 1] === 0 ? arrA[value - 1] = Ob[Columns[i]] : A[value - 1] = Ob[Columns[i]] * A[value - 1]});
```

But I am sure there has to be a more efficient way looping only one time (`char` to `char`) in `S`. Something like the code below. My main issue is managing the number of digits of `Int` (ie. 1, 10, 100, 1000, 10000, etc.) while using the blank space as separators if looping the string per character.

```
A = [...S].forEach(char => {});
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: can you state the input and output data? can you add the code in stack snippets (`<>` in the editor) for a running example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could split the string, reduce the positions by getting the integer and letter part and assign the result of the multiplication of the value at index or one.

```js
const
    data = "1C 5A 10F 1F 5E",
    length = 10,
    object = { "A": 1, "B": 2, "C": 3, "D": 5, "E": 7, "F": 11, "G": 13, "H": 17, "J": 19, "K": 23 },
    result = data
        .split(' ')
        .reduce(
            (r, position) => {
                var  [i, key] = position.match(/\d+|\D/g);
                i--;
                r[i] = (r[i] || 1) * object[key];
                return r;
            },
            Array.from({ length }, _ => 0)
        );

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```